# DbExtensions - WHERE parameter with byte[] value (timestamp)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, dbextensions

I am using this code

```
updateBuilder
    .UPDATE("myTable")
    .SET("UpdatedDate = {0}", updated.UpdatedDate)
    .SET("UpdatedByUserId = {0}", updated.UpdatedByUserId)
    .WHERE("Id = {0}", updated.Id)
    .WHERE("RowVersion = {0}", updated.RowVersion);
```

And the SQL it generates is like this

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE myTable
SET UpdatedDate = @p0, UpdatedByUserId = @p1
WHERE Id = @p2 AND RowVersion = @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10
```

I am guessing that it is adding a value for each element in the byte array, as the property RowVersion = byte[], but how do i fix this?

In entity framework the byte[] is added in SQL like this

```
@3=0x0000000000560F94
```

How can i get my byte array to be this?

Comment: do you know what this means `{0:X}`.. read up here to answer your question / for an explanation on hexidecimal values  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: do a google search how to convert a byte[] to hexadecimal string

Comment: What is the underlying data type for RowVersion?  byte or string?

Comment: In c# row version is byte []. On sql row version is a timestamp column

Comment: try to convert the byte[] to hexadecimal string and then use it instead of directly using byte[]. for the information regarding converting byte[] to hexadecimal string follow the following stackoverflow link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: tried that, but it then puts ' ' around the value in SQL and i get a conversion error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, the answer is [here](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/issues/10).